# Use WolframAlpha to compute the real Fourier series of a function

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, wolfram-alpha

How can I use Wolfram|Alpha to compute the Fourier series (with real coefficients $a_0, a_n$ and $b_n$)? (The 'Fourier series' command seems to summon the complex series)

I.e. $f(x) = x + \pi$ for $-\pi < x < 0$ and $f(x) = \pi - x$ for $0 \leq x < \pi$

$\Rightarrow f(x) \approx \pi/2 + 4/\pi(cos x + \dfrac 1 3 cos 3x + \dfrac 1 5 cos 5x + \cdot \cdot \cdot)$

I know I can use indefinite or definite integrals to check the integration itself, but I'd be interesting to see a complete solution aid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the FourierCosSeries [command](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierCosSeries%5bIf%5bx%3C0%2Cx%2BPi%2CPi-x%5d%2Cx%2C+5%5d). Here is the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FourierCosSeries.html) of it.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at the 'see also' I see that the **FourierTrigSeries** command was what I was actually looking for.

Comment: Ok, no problem :-)

Comment: But how do I get it to show the steps? The Steps-button is missing! :O

Comment: Sadly that is not implemented for every command yet, it is still to be added.